# Отображение нескольких классов в одном окне QML

Tags: qt, qtcreator, qml, qtquick

Условно говоря, есть окно, в котором находится Rectangle и кнопка по нажатию которой Loader загружает AnotherClass.qml в Rectangle. Это работает, как и хотелось, но когда по нажатию уже другой кнопки, из AnotherClass.qml, появляется открывается два окна с MainMenu.qml.

MainMenu.qml:

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "MainMenu.qml"
    
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: window

        Button {
            id: calcButton
            height: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 220

            onClicked: {
                pageLoader.source = "AnotherClass.qml"
            }

        }
        Loader { id: pageLoader; sourceComponent: rect}
   



}
}
```

AnotherClass.qml

```
Rectangle {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

     Button {
            id: calcButton
            height: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 220

            onClicked: {
                pageLoader.source = "MainMenu.qml"
            }
        }
        Loader { id: pageLoader; sourceComponent: rect}
}
```

Я решил попробовать реализовать это другим образом, но проблема осталось той же.

```
Rectangle {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MainMenu{
        id: mm
    } 

    Button {
            id: calcButton
            height: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 220

            onClicked: {
                mm.pageLoader.source = "MainMenu.qml"
            }
        }
}
```

[image: Как это выглядит]

Answer (score 0):

MainMenu это окно, которое вы вставляете в другое - вот оно и появляется как новое. А в первом случае рисуете квадрат поверх содержимого.